# Rounding polygons

Tags: algorithm, box2d, physics, polygons

Earlier I asked a question, but I think I did it wrong..
Anyways. Here's my problem. I have this function that creates polygons from images, but it's pixel perfect, which creates way too many points for a single polygon.. So my question is, how would I round this down? Dumbing the polygon down a bit, making the edges less sharp and removing some edges at the same time? I couldn't find any algorithms for this, so maybe I just fail at searching..

Thanks,
AsterAlff

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Douglas–Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm is intended to simplify polylines

Answer (score 0):

Consider lowering the detail in the image before generating the polygon - it will be less processing to generate the polygons, and they will themselves be simpler. Effectively you are filtering the information out before you generate the polygon instead of after.

I can't say exactly how you should lower the detail without knowing something about the polygon generation algorithm, but consider blurring and/or scaling the image - you mention getting a polygon per pixel, so scaling would at least reduce the number of pixels. Blurring should reduce noise levels, and also eliminate any aliasing in the original image.

I doubt that will solve the whole problem, as nearly straight lines won't become completely straight, but it should be a performance improvement and get you closer to your result.

Comment: That wouldn't be so great, since it would remove freedom from my users and kill the point of my game.

Comment: Perhaps if you gave some example image and polygon it would be more clear what the best solution is.

Comment: There is no example image, nor an example polygon, since they could be anything.